# Convert embedded text to webview android

Tags: android

I have embedded content like this:

```
> "<!-- Markup for HTML (Factors in Placement and Enrollment of Primary
> Care Patientsin YMCA&#39;s Diabetes Prevention Program, Bronx, New
> York,2010-2015) --><div class='rid_08184eef_309335'
> data-apiroot='//tools.cdc.gov/api' data-mediatype='html'
> data-mediaid='309335' data-stripscripts='true'
> data-stripanchors='false' data-stripimages='false'
> data-stripcomments='true' data-stripstyles='true'
> data-cssclasses='syndicate' data-ids='' data-xpath='' data-oe='utf-8'
> data-of='xhtml' data-ns='cdc' data-postprocess='' data-nw='true'
> data-iframe='true' data-cdc-widget='syndicationIframe'
> data-apiembedsrc='//tools.cdc.gov/api/embed/html/js/embed-2.0.3.js'
> data-iframeembedsrc='//tools.cdc.gov/TemplatePackage/contrib/widgets/tp-widget-external-loader.js'></div><script
> src='//tools.cdc.gov/TemplatePackage/contrib/widgets/tp-widget-external-loader.js'
> ></script><noscript>You need javascript enabled to view this content or go to <a
> href='//tools.cdc.gov/api/v2/resources/media/309335/noscript'>source
> URL</a>.</noscript>
```

How to convert this embedded content to webview android